# Magento - Migrate products by copying all database tables with catalog_ prefix

Tags: magento

In order to migrate only the products and categories, I manually copied all the database tables with the catalog_ prefix from one db to another and it seems to have worked rather well.. so far.

But does anyone know if there is anything potentially bad in doing this?

Answer (score 0):

It might be bad if you have custom eav attributes. Also, even core eav attributes ids can mismatch on different magento instances (if you installed different magento versions).

Answer (score 0):

Time will tell. The tables in Magento are pretty much all relational - so if you've missed something with a foreign key dependency - you're bound to run into issues.

What about your custom attributes, attribute sets, historic orders that relate to a certain entity ID etc.

You would be better off exporting and re-importing your catalogue for a "cleaner" approach, although, it will take some time if you have a large catalogue (100k+).

Have a look at Unirgy Rapidlow - it supports features your looking for and we recommend it to a lot of clients as a drop-in replacement for Dataflow.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, guys.

In case anyone is thinking of trying this, some issues did creep in. When creating new products through the admin, I suddenly found I couldn't get them to show up in the front-end.

Also, (this may or may not have been related) I noticed the image upload buttons seemed to have vanished in the Add Product screen.

In the end the paranoia got too much and I was attributing every glitch to the potentially ropey db migration. I scrapped it and took a totally different approach.

Comment: So.. how did you end up doing your migration?

Comment: I created my new magento instance without any products. 
On my database server I kept a copy of the old database next to the new one. 
I then wrote a fairly simple php script which used SQL statements to fetch all the info about each product from the old database and use the magento product create function to create a new product with all those details on the new one. 
It took a while to run, but at least I could see exactly what it was doing.

Comment: Nice. Any chance you could share your import script? (i need to perform the same operation, having a look at your script would probably save me lots of time)